# Ball Lottery Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

Each lottery player has a "number of balls" attribute (an int from 0 - 100)

- Player 1 gets 60 balls marked 0 to 59
- Player 2 gets 20 balls marked 60 79
- Player 3 gets 80 balls marked 80 to 159

A ball is then picked from the bag, whoever gets chosen wins. Obviously the more balls they have in the bag the more chance they have of getting picked.

Initially I thought the best way to code his would be to have an array where each index acts as the ball, and it stores an object (the player). But it seemed a bit overkill (and doesn't scale well) to have an array with 100s of objects just to pick the player and then move on (this is a small function).

I then thought about having ranges marked (i.e. dismissing the numbers in between) so if the number is in between 0 and 59 it must be Player 1 who wins (i.e. having lower and upper bounds). But I'd like some feedback as there is probably a really simple way (that I'm missing) to do this.

Comment: What is the problem with doing ranges? I think that is the best option, and would scale nicely.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Ranges is fine but you'll have to keep track of numbers that have been called out. If the same number is called again, ignore it.

Comment: This question may be better received if you supplied your implementation to Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NickUdell - there is no code to review.

Comment: @Hank not posted here, sure. Which is why I said "supply your implementation" not, "copy this answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store ranges, only probabilities, or in your case the number of balls they have.

Player 1 has 60 balls. You can store that directly as an `int` 60. Player 2 has 20, so store 20. And so on.

Then count the total number of balls (once, or hardcode it if it known statically), and draw a random number between 0 (included) and the number of balls (excluded).

Loop over the players, add up their number of balls as you loop. Return the first player for which the accumulated number of balls is higher than your random number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct Player
{
    int LowestValue;
    int HighestValue;
}

List<Player> players = new List<Player>(
{
    new Player() { 0,59},
    new Player() {60,79},
    new Player() {80,159}
});

Random r = new Random();
int rVal = r.Next(0,players.Last().HighestValue+1);
Player winner = players.Single(s=> s.LowestValue <= rVal && s.HighestValue >= rVal);
```

Obviously, you can put more than just those range numbers in your struct. I assume you want more data associated with your players.

Also note that `Random.Next(Int32, Int32)` returns values between lowest (inclusive) and highest (exclusive) so we have to add one to the `HighestValue`